# Grabbing Content within Frames (not iframes) with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a bunch of jQuery on my website that I built as a normally website with a header, sidebar and then main content. Despite my protests my manager has decided to turn the header, sidebar and main content into different frames as in the `<frame>` tag not iframes. Obviously this causes many issues.

One of them is that my jQuery seems to have broken when calling certain classes. Such as

```
$('.date')
```

I realize that now I have to find a different way to do all my selectors and have tried to dig into the frames content with

```
$('#mainFrame')
```

but that returns the frame with a #document inside and I'm not sure how precede with digging inside the html.

I have tried unsuccessfully to dig in with rather

```
$('#mainFrame').find('html')
```

or

`$('#mainFrame').content('html')`

Any help would be wonderful and save me from hitting my head against the desk.

Edit: Not using plain javascript, I'm using jQuery.

The HTML looks like this. Keep in mind this is not my idea or code, so please don't judge me...I can't change this, just try and work with it.

```
<frameset rows="52,*" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="Top" />

    <frameset rows="*" cols="235,*" framespacing="0" frameborder="no" border="0">
    <frame src="" name="leftFrame" scrolling="Yes" noresize="noresize" id="leftFrame" title="Left" />

    <frame src='' name='mainFrame' id='mainFrame' title='Main' />

</frameset>

<body>
<noframes>
</body>
</noframes>
```

Comment: Tell your manager that the approach doesnt work and the site will be slower sending more http requests. Is like loading 3 pages in one. Your work will take 3 times longer. Whatever changes his mind lol. However, you can probably get it to work, but I would recomend using divs instead of iframes.

Comment: I'm somewhat in a similar situation. A little worse actually, I have a form with a 2 iframes from 2 different domains. `postMessage` is been helpful so far. In our approach (which doesn't look great) we are having all frames (including parent) talk to each other with `postMessage` calls

Comment: @Medda86 There is no convincing him. He's stuck coding in 1995. I even built the entire site without them and he's forcing me to put them back in.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe Oh, I don't know...I have three frame sets, with one frame within each...and then modals that pop up with frames in them. It's getting almost unbearable to read the code...

Comment: Not that I chose this approach or anything... but this has been working for us in this project. I agree with @Medda86 about not going this way tho... if there's no way to dialog with the management, try his manager or the architect or 'higherup', not behind his back, but to voice a (lot of) technical concern(s) and make clear that this is not a good approach and on the long run, as this may lead the organization to waste time and money by putting countless hours in maintenance or upgrades of a not so 'well thought' solution

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe I'm quitting as of tomorrow, precisely because not even the higher ups will listen to me. This project is a lost cause. They already fired the entire development team because of this guys word that frames and newer techniques are not the way to go. I just need this to work and then I'm off to new and better things (Never thought I would be excited about just reading valid code).

Comment: if you just wanna "get it to work" before you walk out, take a deep breath, and play with `postMessage` a little... it sure doesn't look or feel good, but hey, it works (1000 pomodoros later tho :P)

Comment: Oh I've been breathing haha They won't let me use postMessage, I'm not allowed to use any kind of html5 or api's.

Comment: wish you the best of luck :P

Answer (score 0):

Hi first of all you must change your HTML code, removing the "frameset" in the middle.

```
<html> 
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            var frame=document.getElementById("mainFrame"); 
            var innerDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document; 

            console.log(innerDoc);
        };
    </script>
</head>

<frameset rows="52,*" cols="*" frameborder="no" border="0" framespacing="0">
    <frame src="test.html" name="topFrame" scrolling="No" noresize="noresize" id="topFrame" title="Top" />

    <frame src="test.html" name="leftFrame" scrolling="Yes" noresize="noresize" id="leftFrame" title="Left" />

    <frame src="test.html" name='mainFrame' class='mainFrame' id='mainFrame' title='Main' />


</frameset>
</html>
```

Now to find the content of the frame with id "mainFrame" you can add this to the head of your HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var frame=document.getElementById("mainFrame"); 
        var innerDoc = frame.contentDocument || frame.contentWindow.document; 

        console.log(innerDoc);
    };
</script>
```

Comment: it's not an iframe, their actual <frame> tags within <framesets>

Comment: Hi @zazvorniki. Can you post the html code in your question? You've tried the code?

Comment: I have posted the selectors I have tried in the question already. and the html is simply frame sets with frames inside.

Comment: Hi @zazvorniki. I edited my post to find all the "frame" components, and get the "document" of the first one.

Comment: We may have multiple frames, So we can't just take the first frame out of it. It's always better to use name for that frame and access via it.

Comment: Hi @mohamedrias. I completely agree with you, it's just a way of doing this, he could use the "getElementsByTagName", "getElementsByClassName" that will return an array to, or use the "getElementsById".

Comment: I do have multiple frames here, three or them actually, So I rather not grab the first one.

Comment: Hi @zazvorniki. But you have each frame with a different class name or no? So you can use "getElementsByClassName" instead of "getElementsByTagName"

Comment: They do, I responded before you made your edit. It seems though that getElementsByTagName("mainframe"); which is the frames name, is only returning undefined.

Comment: @zazvorniki, if the class name is "mainframe" you must use "getElementsByClassName", you are using "getElementsByTagName".

Comment: the id, and name on the element is both mainFrame. I'm trying to get the content within that frame though.

Comment: Hi @zazvorniki, now with the HTML code is better, you mus change the "name='mainFrame'" to "class='mainFrame'" or just add "class='mainFrame'" , and each frame must have your own class.

Comment: Why would I want to add a class to it, when I have both an id and a name?  It's the classes inside of the frame that I want to call. I am calling getElementsByTagName("mainframe");

Comment: With you're code (even with the class), I'm getting these errors...both in the fiddle and in my code http://jsfiddle.net/9VjJ3/1/

Comment: Hi @zazvorniki, sorry by taking so long time to answer again, it's because I'm making an example for you, the jsFeedle put the code inner a body, so the Frames don't load, you must put the frame set out of the body, than it will work, see the html example in my web site: http://kaypacha.com.br/frameTest.html  I'll edit the answer again.

Comment: Ok, this is returning what I was getting in the beginning the #document... ($('#mainFrame') seemed to be doing the same thing.) What I was having trouble digging into. And is it possible to do this in an external js sheet? I can't do it inline in the page, it's the jQuery I need to edit to grab the right classes and id's in.

Comment: Hi @zazvorniki. They don't do the same thing. with my code you are able to do this "$(innerDoc).find("ul");" and it will return the UL elements. Try or see it in action here: http://kaypacha.com.br/frameTest2.html

Comment: The "$('#mainFrame')" just return the FRAME element, and my code returns the "#document" element inner the frame.

Comment: In the console, they are returning the same thing though...at least they are for me...and if I put this within the js file then it throws the same error as the jsFiddle was giving. And I cannot have it in the head of the document, I'm trying to convert whats in my js file.

Comment: Hi @zazvorniki, see here: http://kaypacha.com.br/frameTest3.html I have all the JS code in a "js" file. And it work's perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for your selector:

```
$( ".iframe_Class_name" ).contents().find( ".class_inside_this_iframe" )
```

Tested fully active sample:

```
 $( "iframe" ).contents().find( "button" ).click(function()
  {//do some magic

  });
```

Comment: There are not iframes, but frames as in the <frame> tag

Answer (score 0):

At first, you just can't get around having to use frames, keep in mind that the  tag is obsoleted in HTML5. If you ever plan on moving up to HTML5, you'll have to use iFrames.

Anyways You could grab the Frame and div you are wanting to manipulate and pass it into a variable.

```
var frameContainer = top.frames["framename"];
```

Then you can do anything you want to it through jQuery.

```
$(frameContainer).find('#AnyContainerID')
```

You can even use classname or any tag selector you would use in jQuery.

Comment: I know, I originally built the site in html5 and had to downgrade everything I did...there goes four weeks of work... Where you have getElementById('statusText'); is that the id of the frame?

Comment: No. That's any id within the frame. The frame is identified by its name

Comment: alright, is there anyway that I can use something other than getElementById...I'm not calling any id's all I have are classes

Comment: You could use "getElementsByClassName", but it will return an array for your.

Comment: Now you can make use of jquery's normal selectors.

Comment: I have updated the answer.  Actually for this method to work, the frame must have a name. Once you get the element, after that you can use all normal jquery methods on to that.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work. The first line even with the right name in it is returning as undefined

Comment: Could you please paste the HTML you are using. I could be able to guide you better

Comment: I just added the html.